# Encode full file to base64 (not only the content)

Tags: java, xml, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode a **XML** file to **base64**.

I'm using this method:

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary( final String fileName ) throws IOException {
    File file = new File( fileName );
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64( FileUtils.readFileToByteArray( file ) );
    return new String( encoded, Charset.forName( "US-ASCII" ) );
}
```

It works quite well, but when I give a XML file as input. It returns the encoded **content** of the file, and not the file itself, so no metadata here.

I'm using https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode by base64 string. And it returns **plain text**, not an **xml file**.

Comment: Base64 is a mechanism to encode bytes.  If you want to encode additional bytes (eg, metadata), you need to pass them in some format.

Comment: XML files _are_ plain text.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to add this meta data in a *clean* way ?

Comment: That's entirely up to you; you need to decide how you want to encode it.